# Rails 3 - get full error message for one field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller

I have `user.errors` which gives all errors in my controller. So, i have the field `:user_login` which has its error(s). How can i get **full** error messages from `user.errors` ONLY for that field?

I can get just text of this field like that:

```
user.errors[:user_login] # Gives that 'can't be empty'
```

But i really want to do something like that

```
user.errors.get_full_message_for_field[:user_login] # 'Your login can't be empty'
```

Comment: [Quv's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837787/rails-3-get-full-error-message-for-one-field#answer-20303640) seems the best bet now. Might be worth switching the accepted answer @ExiRe?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, I know this question was explicitly posted for Rails 3.x, one and a half years ago, but now Rails 4.x seems to have the very method you were wishing, [`full_messages_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_messages_for).

```
user.errors.full_messages_for(:user_login) #=> return an array
# if you want the first message of all the errors a specific attribute gets,
user.errors.full_messages_for(:user_login).first
# or
user.errors.full_messages_for(:user_login)[0]
```

It's less verbose than the previously used `user.errors.full_message(:user_login, user.errors[:user_login].first)`.

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at `full_message` here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_message

A bit verbose but you may be able to do something like:

```
user.errors.full_message(:user_login, user.errors[:user_login])
```

Comment: actually has to be something more like this:
`resource.errors[:user_login].map { |error|
      user.errors.full_message(:user_login, error) }`

Answer (score 2):

```
We can get the error message of particular field by using

<%= resource.errors.full_messages_for(:email).join("") %>

output : Email cant be blank

If you want to check the particular field has error or not then check it by using

resource.errors.include?(:email)

output : true/false
```

Comment: good one for using `full_messages_for`. By the way checking if specific field has error/s or not we can use this also `resource.errors[:field].any?`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet for displaying only the first error for each field.

```
<!-- Display only first error for each field --->
<% entity.attributes.keys.each do |key| %>
    <% if entity.errors.full_messages_for(key.to_sym).length > 0 %>
        <li><%= entity.errors.full_messages_for(key.to_sym).first %></li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```